# Confirm() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this code

```
function popup() {
    //var x;
    var counter = setTimeout(myFun, 15000);
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
       //x = "You pressed OK!";
       clearTimeout(counter);
    } else {
         //x = "You pressed Cancel!";
         myFun();
    }
}

function myFun() {
   //some code here
}
```

Now if user presses `OK/Cancel` in confirm box or closes the confirm box, the code above is executed accordingly.

However the problem is if the user *don't do any of the above things* `myFun()` doesn't get called even after 15 seconds of setTimeout function.

Comment: `confirm` is blocking. If you want other things to happen while the dialog is open, you cannot use it.

Comment: @Bergi yeah confirm is blocking that's what the problem is,is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Create your OWN dialog.

Comment: For example, https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: The code is not clear, so what will the myFun() do. I guess your code is already calling myFun(). Can you log something to your console and make sure it is not calling. This url demonstrates about your question. Please check it. http://www.coderanch.com/t/116075/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/timeout-confirm-dialog

Comment: There are plenty of JS-modal dialog implementations you can investigate that would be similar to the built-in alert/prompt/confirm ones but with more flexibility.  A search for "Javascript modal dialog" should do you fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the MSDN stipulates, there is only a parameter for the text to display in the confirmation. therefore, there is no way within the method itself to tell it to assume something after X number of seconds, as opposed to the way a confirm box works in VBScript.

Essentially, your javascript stops at the point of a popup prompt. even if you had a setimeout that tried to force a return in the scope of the popup prompt, it wouldnt complete until the popup prompt it was trying to affect was acknowledged. for instance, make a for loop of "alert("hi")"'s that goes for 50 iterations. you will get them not all at once, but one after another as the script stops between each prompt.

Suggestion: Therefore, it is best to create a popup window with HTML to display to the user. if you fear that popups are blocked, then create something within the HTML document itself perhaps using DHTML or you can use the jquery-ui modal.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) to emulate the confirm box.